# Do other intelligent beings exist in some other planet besides man according to Quran or Hadith?

Tags: science

Does Quran or Hadith mention any other intelligent beings in the universe like humans maybe on some other planet? Except for Jin and Angels which are mentioned in Quran.

Prophet (P.B.U.H) was given the title of Rehmat-ul-Alamin. And generally the word Alamin is used for man, jin, angels and everything else. How does that fit with the theory of existence of any other being on any other planet?

Comment: Qur'an and hadith are here as sources of divine guidance, not sience. They don't answer every scientific question at all, or in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clear information about aliens in Quran or hadiths.

One can bring these ayats in counter:

> قُل لَّا يَعْلَمُ **مَن فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ** وَالْأَرْضِ الْغَيْبَ إِلَّا اللَّهُ وَمَا يَشْعُرُونَ أَيَّانَ يُبْعَثُونَ
>   Say, "None in the heavens and earth knows the unseen except Allah , and they do not perceive when they will be resurrected."
>   Naml 65 (27/65)

-

> وَرَبُّكَ أَعْلَمُ **بِمَن فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ** وَالأَرْضِ وَلَقَدْ فَضَّلْنَا بَعْضَ النَّبِيِّينَ عَلَى بَعْضٍ وَآتَيْنَا دَاوُودَ زَبُورًا
>   And your Lord is most knowing of whoever is in the heavens and the earth. And We have made some of the prophets exceed others [in various ways], and to David We gave the book [of Psalms].
>   Isra 55 (17/55)

-

> إِن كُلُّ **مَن فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ** وَالْأَرْضِ إِلَّا آتِي الرَّحْمَنِ عَبْدًا
>   There is no one in the heavens and earth but that he comes to the Most Merciful as a servant.
>   Maryam 93 (19/93)

In these ayats, the bold written part in the original Arabic text, the phrase literally means `who is in the skies`. The word "who" in these phrases is not the question word; it is for making relative clauses. Anyway, the word `مَن (who)` is used for beings with human-level consciousness (i.e.; intelligent beings). For less intelligent beings (like animals, plants and objects), `مَا (what)` is used.

However, the words `سما (sky)`, `ارض (earth)` and many other natural words are highly symbolic (mutashabih) words, and almost always used for symbolic expressions; they both symbolize certain something, but it is not our topic here.

If we trace the meaning of these words in the entire Quran, we see that `sky` is not used for deep space where aliens would live in.

Note that, Quran also does not say that there are no aliens.

Quran is a book for:

- Showing the people the path for keeping their society in the optimum (stable) state.
- Warning the people about `sa'at (the point in which corruption of a society starts; the point of no return)`
- Warning the people about The Final Day (ahirat) in which all people will revive and be asked for what they had spent their lives for.
- Being a `zikr (finding solutions to our daily life problems by using the basic current data/informations)`.

Talking about aliens is outside of Quran's general scope.
I don't say that Quran has **no** information about aliens. It just have no direct information. Directly and clearly does not mention them. No one can fully understand Quran, so I can't say that something is absolutely not mentioned in it. Maybe one day, someone can find it in Quran; who knows?

Hadiths are the outcome of the nabi Muhammad's 23 year of study and practice of Quran. They are not something too different from Quran. So, they also doesn't mention anything about aliens.

Comment: Do you understand what this answer turn into in meaning when the symbolism subject is removed from it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, In Quran there is a verse in which allah talah says i have created the heavens and the earth and have scattered my creations between the,which means between them lies the whole universe and obviously there are many creations we dont know about other than us on earth and angels in the heaven.

Comment: Salaam and welcome to islam.SE - please take a look at the FAQ before getting started asking or answering questions. Also please take a look at highly upvoted questions and answers to get an idea of the quality we expect on this website. If you have any questions you're welcome to join us in the chatroom.

Answer (score 0):

Surah Rahman : talks about two kinds of life. Man and Jinn.  Man made from mud ( solid state, sodium potassium calcium iron molybdenium etc. all the minerals that are there in the mud - earth)
Then Jinn : made of fire. 
Then Allah describes  himself as the Sustainer of the two Easts and two Wests.
So could he be referring to the East and West of Earth and then the East and West of another Planet or Star that is made of combustible gases from which the Jinn are made of. 
I only imagine how are the Jinn how are they intellectual like humans with power of memmory , descretion between right and wrong. When we made of mud have this shape of bones muscles and organs. How do the Jinn look alike . May be they are in the Sun and its rays , taking different shapes and functions. may be the other gaseous planets like jupiter neptune etc.
and When there is description of a day equal to 1000yrs in one place and 50000 yrs in another place , I wonder which planet has a day that is equal to 1000 yrs and 500000 yrs. Only astronomers and study of astronomy with these questions in mind will clarify the statements in Qur'an Insallaha.

Comment: Please take the time to format your posts properly and use correct grammar.  As written, this post is hard to read and, as best I can tell, is nothing more than speculation rather than an actual *answer*.  It runs a very high risk of being deleted.